# Do I need to pay tax in USA for money remitted

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, money-transfer

I am planning to transfer money from India to USA. Do I need to pay tax in USA for the money inwardly remitted. If yes, what is the percentage rate?

Comment: If it is your own money there is no tax moving it across the US border (though there maybe other issues to make clear that this isn't a transfer for illegal purposes).. If it is income from someone else, tax is due.

Comment: @keshlam, this is my money and certainly not for illegal purposes. Is there any official reference to confirm what you mentioned? Please let me know.

Comment: @Chandra there's no tax on moving money into the US. Official references exist for laws that are on the books. There's no official reference to say that a certain law is *not* on the books.